# jquery slide hidden menu from left can't configure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate

So I've been working on this for a while, I've tried many examples found here on stackoverflow, and then starting reading up on js/jquery for most of the day, but am still having trouble with this.

Basically I was able to create a hidden menu item that slides on to screen when clicked, and I was able to change the button used to open in by toggling the class, and send it back.

But after the first time through that process when I try to open it again, it opens and then closes automatically.

I built a jsfiddle, but have done it wrong as it's not working the same as on my site.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VpnrV/1/

site: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev4/

code - html:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <nav id="access">
        <div class="open"></div>Here's a bunch of content representing the nav bar.
    </nav>
</div> <!-- dashboard -->
```

css:

```
#dashboard {
  font-size:30px;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  right: -653px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#access {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width:730px;
}

.open {
  background: #cabd32 url(images/open.png) top left no-repeat;
  float:left;
  padding:13px 30px 16px;
}

.close {
  background: #cabd32 url(images/close.png) top left no-repeat;
  float:left;
  padding:13px 30px 16px;
}
```

my laughable js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.open').click(function() {
        $('#dashboard').animate({ right: '0' });
            $(this).toggleClass('close'); 
            $('.close').click(function() {
            $('#dashboard').animate({right: '-653'});
         }
  );
 });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually binding the class .close to multiple callback every time you click the button.

you can try this:

```
$('.open').bind('click',function(){ 
    $('#dashboard').stop().animate(
    {
        right: $(this).hasClass('close') ? '-653px' : '-400px'
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});
```

Having stop() infront of animate() will cancel the current animation and do the next animation without queueing multiple animations up.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCheuk this works beautifully, except that I just noticed, though the div 'dashboard' is being pushed off screen, I'm actually getting a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the screen to account for the amount is pushed to the right. Should I perhaps start a new thread for that question?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this in one click event. All this does is every time you click open it looks for the close class, if it's there, close the menu, if not open it. Then toggle the `close` class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.open').on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('close')) {
            $('#dashboard').animate({
                right: '-653'
            });
        } else {
            $('#dashboard').animate({
                right: '0'
            });
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

I don't know if this is the most effecient but it works for your example. I updated it as well: http://jsfiddle.net/VpnrV/3/

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks so much. Looking forward to picking this apart and seeing where my errors were.

Comment: What I think was going on with your code was having the close click binding occur inside the open click binding. So when you clicked it the second time, it bound a second click event to close, that's why clicking it would open the close it right away because it was adding multiple click events that did different actions to the same element.